# Is my son's math book key in error?

Tags: arithmetic

My son's math book key gives a different answer than what my wife and I consider the right answer. We both worked independently with our son and I asked two other people (both of whom came to the same conclusion). What's important here is that either we need to be corrected or our son needs to know he can trust in our abilities to help him learn math.

> Your friend spends one third of her money on lunch. You then give her
>   \$2.50 to repay a loan. After school, your friend spends \$4.00 for a
>   movie and \$2.50 for a snack. She has \$4.90 left. How much money did
>   she have before lunch?

I worked it out this way:

```
2/3m + 2.50 (loan repayment) - 4.00 - 2.50 = 4.90

2/3m - 4.00 - 2.50 = 4.90 - 2.50 = 2.40 (cancelling out the loan repayment)

2/3m = 2.40 + 4.00 + 2.50 = 8.90

8.90 / 2 = 4.45

4.45 * 3 = 13.35 = m
```

Comment: @MJD thanks for the edit.

Comment: The posted solution is correct (I would simply cancel the positive and negative \$2.50 myself).

Comment: What you did looks correct.  What answer did the book have?

Comment: Your solution is correct.

Comment: What did the answer key say?

Comment: Wouldn't be the first error in a textbook...

Comment: The answer key said twice that amount: $26.70

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your answer is correct; the only critique I have with the way you have written it would be to write $2/3$ in parentheses (i.e., $(2/3)m$ instead of $2/3m$) to avoid confusion with whether $m$ is mulitplying or dividing.